# Read excel with two-line headers in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, spreadsheet

I have an excel file with the simple structure like on picture below.

[image: Excel structure]

```
        A                       B       
a       b       c       a       b        c
0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42
0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42    0.42
```

How can I get to a data.frame in R as shown below?

```
col_name    a       b       c
A           0.42    0.42    0.42
A           0.42    0.42    0.42
B           0.42    0.42    0.42
B           0.42    0.42    0.42
```

An important addition. Sample structure - is only a part of whole table.

Whole excel looks like:

[image: Whole document]

Comment: `library(readxl); read_excel(filename, skip = 1)`

Comment: This is not the answer to my question.  After reading document I need to transform it to result dataframe.  If I skip first line, I can't get the values for my col_name.Moreover, I also need to "combine" two parts A and B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the Excel file is small, I would approach it like this.

```
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

cols <- read_excel("path_to_file.xlsx", 
                   col_names = FALSE)[1:2, ]

cols[1, ] <- na.locf(as.character(cols[1, ]),
                     na.rm = FALSE)

cols <- vapply(X = cols,
               FUN = function(x) if (is.na(x[1])) x[2] else paste0(x, collapse = "_"),
               FUN.VALUE = character(1))

DFrame <- read_excel("path_to_file.xlsx", 
                     col_names = FALSE,
                     skip = 2) %>%
  setNames(cols) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number())

DFrame

DFrame %>%
  select(row_id, A_a:B_c) %>%
  gather(column, value, A_a:B_c) %>%
  mutate(AB_group = sub("(^[A-B])_.+$", "\\1", column),
         column = sub("^[A-B]_", "", column)) %>%
  dcast(row_id + AB_group ~ column, 
        value.var = "value")
```

The downside is that, since `read_excel` doesn't have an `nrows` argument, this code actually reads the file in twice.  There are other packages that can read excel files, such as `gdata::read.xls` that will let you only read in the top two rows to get the column names. I think that package has a little more overhead.

Regardless, when I face this situation, I either import the column names separately and manipulate them to what I want before assigning them to the data, or I just don't read in the names at all and manually reset all of the variable names using `setNames`.